# Why $routeChangeStart fires twice in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, rootscope

I have this function, when it's executed, it's fired twice. I see `alert(ok)` then `alert(ok)` I don't know why.

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

    if ( next.templateUrl == "partials/login.html" ) {
       alert( "ok" );
       $location.path( "/login" );
    } 

}
```

Comment: Where are your controllers? Where do you call this function from? If you call the controller twice it might fire twice

Answer (score 0):

My routes changes twice because I wanted to reach url which doesn't exist, so finally to redirect me to `/`